# Querying the users table in db, doesnt reflect changes

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, simplemembership

I´m having this table, "Users" where i store UserID, Email and CompanyID. I´m using simplemembership on the site.

When a user log in, everything is ok and i can access the CompanyID, but if i change the CompanyID in the DB, this doesnt reflects on the site.

If i try this query: `dbContext.Users.Find(id).CompanyID` it still returns the old CompanyID. If i wait some time, the update is reflected, but why is it not reflecting the new db-value at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework caches the results.

Please search for how to turn off caching on entity framework, to know more about this.

Comment: But why is it only caching the users table?